# How can I get my batch script to run a set of commands if apache-tomcat is running?

Tags: batch-file, tomcat7

I am using apache-tomcat 7 to host a web app locally for development. The issue I'm having is that I want my batch script to shutdown the possibly running other instances of tomcat. But I only want to try to shutdown tomcat if it is currently running. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this (set Task as appropriate):

```
SET "Task=Tomcat.exe"
TASKLIST /NH /V | FIND /I "%Task%" && (ECHO.%Task% is running. We will now shut it down & TASKKILL /IM "%Task%" /F)
```